# What is easy composition in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173173(v=vs.80).aspx), it is recommended to use delegates when **Easy composition is desired**.
Can someone explain with an example what **Easy Composition** is?

Comment: I know what Composition is. But MSDN says Easy Composition? Is there any differences?

Comment: Easy means something that is more simple to achieve than hard. Definition: `achieved without great effort; presenting few difficulties.`

Comment: Don't understand that instance of "Easy Composition" (note capital letters) as some pre-defined technical term. They simply mean "easy composition" (in the sense of "composition" that is easy to achieve) as opposed to a form of "composition" that takes some more work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example will help.

Imagine that you have a class which needs to output some logging messages, and you want to use constructor dependency injection to provide to that class a means to log messages.

You have several options, including:

1. Pass to the class constructor an interface which includes a method for logging messages.
2. Pass to the class constructor a delegate which directly logs a message.

The interface might look something like this:

```
public interface Log
{
    void WriteLine(string message);

    // ... Other methods
}
```

And the class might therefore look like this:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
    readonly ILog _log;

    public MyClass(ILog log)
    {
        _log = log;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        _log.WriteLine("Test() called");
    }
}
```

This class is now coupled to the `ILog` interface, and when constructing it you must have to supply an object which implements `ILog`.

If you use a delegate instead, the class could look like this:

```
public sealed class MyClass
{
    readonly Action<string> _writeLogLine;

    public MyClass(Action<string> writeLogLine)
    {
        _writeLogLine = writeLogLine;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        _writeLogLine("Test() called");
    }
}
```

Now the class is no longer coupled to `ILog`, and when constructing it you can pass to it any method that matches the delegate:

```
var myClass = new MyClass(Console.WriteLine);
```

This makes the composition of `MyClass` easier - hence ***Easy composition***.

Comment: Matthew Watson and @stakx, you guys really answered the question. I will give both points but I see Matthew Watson's answer is more correct that is why I can only tick his answer.

Answer (score 3):

This MSDN article compares usage of interfaces vs usage of delegates in certain situations. It says that delegates provide easy composition compared to interfaces. What does it mean? Suppose you have such interface:

```
interface ICanWrite {
    void Write();
}
```

Now you have two instances of such interface:

```
ICanWrite first;
ICanWrite second;
```

How do you compose them? So, how do you get new `ICanWrite` instance which `Write` method will perform both `first.Write` and `second.Write`? Not easy.

Now suppose you use delegates instead of interfaces:

```
static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Action write = null; // Action is a delegate type
    write += () => Console.WriteLine("one"); // first write
    write += () => Console.WriteLine("two"); // composition, looks quite easy compared to interfaces
    write(); // both delegates are executed ("one two")       
}
```

Comment: That doesn't *explain* anything

Comment: @musefan Sure it does. It shows that a single delegate can compose of many delegates (composition) and demonstrates the `+=` operator, which makes the composition syntactically easy.

Comment: @musefan expanded a bit.

Comment: @Spender: I didn't say it doesn't show anything, I said it doesn't explain anything. It only 'shows' something to you because you already understand it. Though the answer is edited now with explanation so doesn't really matter...

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand "easy composition" as "Easy Composition", when in fact it isn't meant to be a technical term of its own. They simply mean that composition can be easier to achieve (i.e. require less work) with delegates than with interfaces.

If you've been a .NET programmer for a little while, you'll likely know the `System.Action` delegate. You can get a glimpse of what the MSDN article means when you compare `System.Action` with what it would look like if it were an interface:

```
delegate void Action();

interface IAction
{
    void Execute();
}
```

The delegate is a one-liner, whereas the interface takes some more typing, and one needs to come up with an additional name for the method.

What the MSDN article is really about is the use of delegates vs. interfaces. Let's say you have some method that takes a callback handler, `onCompleted`:

```
void DoSomethingThatTakesVeryLong(Action onCompleted)
{
    // do something that might take a while:
    …
    // notify the caller that we're done:
    onCompleted();
}
```

Now what would it take to use this method?

In the case where `onCompleted` is of a delegate type, you can write the following:

```
DoSomethingThatTakesVeryLong(() => Console.WriteLine("Done."));
```

If `onCompleted` however were of an interface type (let's assume `IAction` above), you'd have to wrap the callback code in a type implementing `IAction`:

```
class DoneLogger : IAction
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
    }
}

DoSomethingThatTakesVeryLong(new DoneLogger());
```

This is a lot more work: You need to wrap very simple code in a class that isn't really necessary, you need to come up with a name for that class, you need to instantiate the class. Now imagine that there were no delegates, and you'd always have to do that... that'd be a lot of boilerplate code.

I hope that helped you see just how delegates can mean less work than interfaces.